# Is there a way to view all shapes used in a power point presentation?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I am working on a presentation with about 150 combined tables and charts to keep track of. The selection and visibility pane (Picture Tools > Arrange > Selection Pane) lets me name and view a list of all shapes on a slide, but is there an option to go up a level and view a list of all the shapes used in the entire presentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, PowerPoint doesn't have any feature that would allow you to do this.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Perhaps there's some other way.

Comment: The company I work for uses PowerPoint as a layout software for publication purposes. This is an established method for them, and I don’t have the kind of influence to convince an entire department to switch to a software like Adobe Pagemaker, or even Microsoft Word for that matter.

Comment: One of my primary jobs is to create the reports along with the charts and tables to go in them, at an average of 100 figures and 50 tables per publication. Each report ends up being about 70-90 pages on average, and so keeping track of the locations of each figure within the presentation is at present very hard. I’d love to find a way to create a table of figures that updates the slide location automatically in case of adding or removing slides between.

Comment: Something that would update automatically would be quite difficult to write, but re-creating such a report would likely take a minute or so. Uniquely identifying each table/figure would be the tricky part. How might you identify the figure on slide 42 so the code could recognize it and report it to the user in a meaningful fashion?

Comment: Within a report I name tables and figures in order of their appearance from top to bottom going clockwise. I have already gone through and named each image so when I go to the selection pane for slide 42, I can see it contains figures 74 and 75, and table 21 (figures and tables are counted separately). This is different from the order they may have been created in, it could be content from survey question 12 and 66. If there was a way to include input from the alt text there could be a description of each figure/table in there. Is that what you’re asking?

Comment: I don’t expect the figures and tables to automatically label themselves, but if I need to make some space for commentary and I bump something over to another slide, that’s what would be helpful to track. At the end, I need to make sure that everything goes somewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a solution to this; w/o some way of identifiying the figures/tables, the best a report could give you is:  There's a table on slide 14.  And perhaps  a bit of text from the table.

Comment: I probably just don’t understand the question...what do you mean by “identifying?” Would I need to assign some sort of ID number to each one?

Comment: There are different ways to embed objects in PowerPoint. If I were to embed links is there a report that could tell me what links each slide contains? The links would have to be unique, right

Comment: A links report is easy. I have a commercial add-in that helps fix broken links.  The free demo does a link report, listing the links on each slide.  It's called PTools FixLinks. For what you're talking about, consider it a freebie; the paid version wouldn't add any value in your case.  http://www.pptools.com/fixlinks/index.html

Comment: thank you for this link! Glad to know about these add-ins. I actually found a related question on Stack Overflow and adapted VBA from there to generate a list of figures and tables per slide. Unfortunately, if I want to see objects printed in ascending order I have to manually arrange the selection pane objects in descending order, but other than this quirk it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to provide a partial answer to my own question, above, based on VBA found in the following thread on stack overflow: [VBA to list all object names of a powerpoint presentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49363950/vba-to-list-all-object-names-of-a-powerpoint-presentation)

This solution technically allows a person to view all the shapes used in a Power Point presentation via a text file report.

```
Sub ListAllShapes()

    Dim curSlide As Slide
    Dim curShape As Shape
    Dim lFile As Long
    Dim sPath As String

    sPath = ActivePresentation.Path

    lFile = FreeFile

    Open sPath & "\All Shapes.txt" For Append As #lFile

    For Each curSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        Print #lFile, "SLIDE " & curSlide.SlideNumber
        For Each curShape In curSlide.Shapes
                Print #lFile, "    " & curShape.Name
        Next curShape
    Next curSlide

    Close #lFile

End Sub
```

This generates a text report which looks like this:

```
SLIDE 1
    Rectangle 2
    Rectangle 4
    Rectangle 4
    TextBox 10
    Rectangle 4
SLIDE 2
    TextBox 7
    Rectangle 2
    Rectangle 4
    Rectangle 4
    Line 37
    Picture 1
    Picture 2
SLIDE 3
    Rectangle 2
    Rectangle 4
    Rectangle 7
    TextBox 7
    Line 28
    Picture 3
    Picture 4, etc...
```

For my particular use-case, I wanted a list of only certain shapes per slide, which I achieved by first using the selection pane to name each picture containing a figure or table with an appropriate prefix and then running this:

```
Sub ListFiguresAndTables()

    Dim curSlide As Slide
    Dim curShape As Shape
    Dim lFile As Long
    Dim sPath As String

    sPath = ActivePresentation.Path

    lFile = FreeFile

    Open sPath & "\Figures and Tables.txt" For Append As #lFile

    For Each curSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        Print #lFile, "SLIDE " & curSlide.SlideNumber
        For Each curShape In curSlide.Shapes
            If Left(curShape.Name, 4) = "Fig." Or Left(curShape.Name, 5) = "Table" Then
                Print #lFile, "    " & curShape.Name
            End If
        Next curShape
    Next curSlide

    Close #lFile

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, the only way I can get the macro to print these objects in ascending order is if I use the selection pane to manually arrange shapes in the opposite (descending) order first.

```
SLIDE 1
    Fig. 1
    Fig. 2
    Fig. 3
    Table 1
SLIDE 2
    Fig. 4
    Fig. 5
    Fig. 6  
SLIDE 3
    Table 2
    Table 3 (etc.)
```